# connection refused while hitting an api through rest assured in selenium

Tags: eclipse, rest, selenium

Hi i am using client server, i want to fetch the response from an api which is invoking after clicking a button through selenium code , i create one method to invoke that API, but i got an error connection refused.below is my method :

```
Response response = RestAssured.get("https://diveui-dive-nonprod.telitcaas1.t-internal.com/case-requirement-service/1.0/caseGroupRequirement/BPFRMHAKEL/0");
        CaseRequirement caseRequirement =  (CaseRequirement) response.getBody();
        System.out.println("Response Body is =>  " + caseRequirement.getRequirementId());

        return String.valueOf(caseRequirement.getRequirementId());

    }
```

can someone help me on this?

Comment: does you abl eto do it manually , try it in postman and check if you able to see , it seems to have missed the headers

Comment: That might be a proxy issue

Comment: @AlexeyR.:how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: @shubham jain: yeah i will try in postman

Comment: @ShubhamJain:it is working in postman

Comment: it is a get api.. can someone help me to resolbe this

Comment: this is the error which is coming                                                                                                 java.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: Does in postman you have put any headers?

Comment: @ShubhamJain-no

Comment: @ShubhamJain: this is the get api which i used https://diveui-dive-nonprod.telitcaas1.t-internal.com/case-requirement-service/1.0/caseRequirement/YJCPT7J70K/0